# How to differentiate created objects and updated objects in Django bulk_create?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-orm

I am using **bulk_create** to create objects in one query. I set `update_conflicts` to True to update permission level if the record already exists. `bulk_create` returns the
created and updated objects. How can I separate the created object and updated ones?

```
class UserPermission(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='permissions')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='permissions')
    permission_level = models.SmallIntegerField(default=1)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('project', 'user')
```

```
permissions = UserPermission.objects.bulk_create(
            user_permissions,
            update_conflicts=True,
            update_fields=['permission_level'],
            unique_fields=['project', 'user'],
        )
```